# Log4j2 RollingFile appender start archiving after N days?

Tags: configuration, log4j2

This is the conf I am using at the moment:

```
<RollingFile name="RollingFileAppender"
    fileName="/tmp/test.log" filePattern="/tmp/test-%i.log.gz" ignoreExceptions="false">
  <PatternLayout pattern="%m%n" />
  <Policies>
    <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB" />
  </Policies>
  <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5" />
</RollingFile>
```

Notice the '.gz' extension that make log4j2 compress the rotated log files.

I would like to keep 5 files uncompressed and start compressing only after that.
Is there a way to start the compression after N rotations?

Comment: I had the same problem, I replied to myself in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37841870/log4j2-archive-every-week-rotate-every-startup/37881591#37881591