# log4j2 archive every week, rotate every startup?

Tags: configuration, rotation, log4j, archive, log4j2

I am trying to figure out how to simply rename the active log file on every startup, and archive all the rotated files once a week.

I am forced to specify the "filePattern" at the RollingFile appender declaration, instead of at the policy. Do this make sense?

Comment: similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30880246/log4j2-rollingfile-appender-start-archiving-after-n-days

Comment: The OnStartupTriggeringPolicy is designed to allow you to roll the log file on every startup. 

What exactly do you mean by "archive all the rotated files once a week"? Are wanting to move them to some other place at that time? Are you running on a Unix system? If so, creating a cron job to move the files is pretty simple.

Comment: Yes, I want to zip old logs, when they are too old.... It should be done by the logging system I believe, not by a system task.... I believe this was possible with log4j 1.

Comment: I don't recall seeing a feature in Log4j 1 where it would zip old log files, but I could be mistaken.  You should create an enhancement request for Log4j 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up doing my own implementation of a DeleteAction, and attaching it to a DefaultRolloverStrategy, so that it is zipping everything before deleting. You can find the sourcecode at:

https://github.com/lqbweb/log4j2-ZipDelete